# Errors with long long and string or sth else

Tags: c++

I'm coding C++ and want to see if a number is divisible by the total sum of its digits. However, I found a problem where it shouldn't have been. so here's my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long n, a=0;
    string s;
    cin>>n;
    s=to_string(n);
    for (long long i=1; i<=s.size(); i++){a=a+s[i-1];}
    if (n%a==0){cout<<"YES";}
    else {cout<<"NO";}
    return 0;
}
```

I tried with 12, but it returned no instead of yes. I tried printing values of s and a, but nothing worked. I thought that there was a problem with this part:

```
a=a+s[i-1];
```

If anyone is willing to help, thanks! I appreciate it.

Comment: You already found your mistake. Thats right, its on the `a=a+s[i-1];` part. You cannot add `a` and `s` together since `a` is a long long and `s` is a string.

Comment: `s[i-1]`  is a character. So you need `s[i-1] - '0'` to get the digit you want.

Comment: To begin with: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) And [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) Whatever resource that taught you those things, you should get a new one.

Comment: If you're really serious about learning C++, please invest in [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Then how do I convert a character to a number? (not ASCII value)

Comment: Digits are guaranteed (by the C++ specification) to always be contiguously encoded, no matter the encoding scheme. So it's guaranteed that `'0' < '1'`, and `'1' < '2'` etc. *And* it's also guaranteed that the difference between two consecutive digits will always be `1`. So `'1' - '0'` is always `1`, `'2' - '0'` is always `2`, etc. Now sit down and think about that a little, and I'm sure you will figure something out. By the way, a decent learning or teaching resource should have already taught you this.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't summing the digits, you're summing the *character values* of the digits.  For example the character value of `'0'` is 48.  Easy to fix though:

```
a=a+(s[i-1]-'0');
```

Comment: ah I understand now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As i said in the comments, the mistake lies in the addition part in your for loop. You cannot add a long long and a string together. you should try doing this:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long n, a=0,m;
    cin>>n;
    m=n;
   while(n!=0)
   {
     a+=(n%10);
     n/=10;
   }
    if (m % a == 0){cout<<"YES";}
    else {cout<<"NO";}
    return 0;
}
```

in this code, I made multiple changes. in the code, the while loop loops until the `n` is equal to 0. It loops and then adds the last digit of `n` to `a`. then `n` gets divided by 10 and the last digit is then removed from `n`. This happens until `n` is equal to 0. after that, the check happens if the number is divisible by `a`. Since `n` is 0 now, there is another variable `m` used instead. `m` stores the value of `n` before the loop , so it would have the original value. Now when checking, if `m` is divisible by `a`, it will print yes and if not , it will print no.

Tell me if it works or not. Reminder though, this is just another way to do this work. There are many other ways to do this same thing, maybe an even shorter way to do it.